# Getting Integrate to perform numerical integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to calculate the mutual impedance of two antennas which is just a big integral. I defined my function in terms of my variable, but when I execute it, Mathematica runs for a while and then just gives back my original equation, just a little bit expanded. It does not show any errors, just runs for a while and spits out my unintegrated equation. My exact code is below:

```
(* this part is just setting up the equations I will be using in my integral *)
Sza[s_, θ_]            := s*Cos[θ]
Sya[s_, θ_, φ_]        := s*Sin[θ]*Sin[φ]
Sxa[s_, θ_, φ_]        := s*Sin[θ]*Cos[φ]
ρa[Sx_, y0_, Sy_]      := Sqrt[Sx^2 + (y0 + Sy)^2]
ra[ρ_, z0_, Sz_]       := Sqrt[ρ^2 + (z0 + Sz)^2]
r1a[ρ_, z0_, Sz_, L1_] := Sqrt[ρ^2 + (z0 + Sz + L1/2)^2]
r2a[ρ_, z0_, Sz_, L1_] := Sqrt[ρ^2 + (z0 + Sz - L1/2)^2]

(* Defining the integral equation *)
R21[ρ_, r1_, Sz_, z0_, L1_, r2_, r_, Sx_, y0_, Sy_, L2_] := -30*
Integrate[
    (((1/ρ^2)*(Sin[2*Pi*r1]*((Sz + z0 + L1/2)/r1) + 
        Sin[2*Pi*r2]*((Sz + z0 - L1/2)/r2) - 
        2*Cos[Pi*L1]*Sin[2*Pi*r]*((Sz + z0)/r))*(Sx^2 + y0*Sy + 
        Sy^2)) + ((2*Sin[2*Pi*r]*Cos[Pi*L1]/r - Sin[2*Pi*r1]/r1 - 
        Sin[2*Pi*r2]/r2)*Sz))*(Sin[2*Pi*(L2/2 - Abs[s])]/s),
    {s, -L2/2, L2/2}]

(*Calculating constants *)
Sz = Sza[s, 1/4*Pi]
Sy = Sya[s, 1/4*Pi, 1/4*Pi]
Sx = Sxa[s, 1/4*Pi, 1/4*Pi]
ρ  = ρa[Sx, .6175, Sy]
r  = ra[ρ, .103, Sz]
r1 = r1a[ρ, .103, Sz, .395]
r2 = r2a[ρ, .103, Sz, .395]

(*Executing the integration equation, with constants plugged in *)
R21[ρ, r1, Sz, .103, .395, r2, r, Sx, .6175, Sy, 1.63]
```

After that, it ran for about 2 hours, and then just spit out `R21` in its integration form.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NIntegrate` to perform numerical integration (simply replace `Integrate` with `NIntegrate` in the definition of `R21`). On my laptop, it spits out the numerical value of the result in 0.3 s (and the result is 9.46643, by the way).

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: So did you use `Timing` or `AbsoluteTiming` to figure out how long it took for the code to run?

Comment: I did not but all I cared about is that it gave me an answer in less than a second. This is weird about integrate though, I always used Integrate for numerical computations and had no problems. Guess it uses a different method.

Comment: @DNA `AbsoluteTiming`, why?

Comment: @F'x Oh, just curious!