# Movable text on a curve

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry, text, geometric-transform

Having an arbitrary curve defined as `InterpolatingFunction`, what is the best way to place a text on this curve? The text generally has two rows, for example: `"This is\na text on a curve"`, the curve must go between the rows. I am interested both in character-based (preserving characters as selectable textual elements) and outlined solution (the text is first converted to outlines, then a transformation is applied to the resulting curves). It would be perfect to have a possibility to move the text along the curve interactively.

External links (updated!):

1. [Warping Text to a Bézier curves (Jay's Projects)](http://www.planetclegg.com/projects/WarpingTextToSplines.html)
2. [**Geometric shaping of a text** (Wolfram Community)](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/765198)

---

For the search engine: this is also known as "text on a path."

Comment: Related: [How can I wrap text around a circle?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5719/121)

Comment: Likely necessary for a solution: [Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8454/121)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's another way...Text[] has a direction argument, so ArcTan is not necessary.

```
txt1 = "Now we can follow" // Characters;
txt2 = "an arbitrary path" // Characters;
f[t_] := {Cos[2 π t], Sin[6 π t]};
totalarclength = NIntegrate[Sqrt[f'[τ].f'[τ]], {τ, 0, 1}];
invarclength = First@NDSolve[{D[$t[s], s] == 1/Sqrt[f'[$t[s]].f'[$t[s]]], $t[0] == 0},
$t, {s, 0, totalarclength}];
ds = 0.12;
fs = Scaled[0.08];

Manipulate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}],
    Graphics[{
      Table[Text[Style[txt1[[n]], "Text", FontSize -> fs],
        f[$t[Mod[s0 + n ds, totalarclength]] /. invarclength],
        {0, -1.1},
        f'[$t[Mod[s0 + n ds, totalarclength]] /. invarclength]],
        {n, Length[txt1]}], 
      Table[Text[Style[txt2[[n]], "Text", FontSize -> fs],
        f[$t[Mod[s0 + n ds, totalarclength]] /. invarclength],
        {0, 1.1},
        f'[$t[Mod[s0 + n ds, totalarclength]] /. invarclength]],
        {n, Length[txt2]}]}],
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.09]
  ],
  {s0, 0, totalarclength}
]
```

Computing the arclength can help space the characters out.  As far as I know, Mathematica does not provide access to character widths, so that equal spacing is probably as good as one can do easily.  As someone has remarked, tight curvatures pose a problem.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Addendum**

One of Alexey Popkov's comments suggested the following modification, with help from the FilledCurve doc page.  The glyphs are distorted by the curvature, and tight curvatures cause inversion.

```
txtbase = ImportString[ExportString["some movable text", "PDF"], "PDF"];
txt = First@First@txtbase;
xRange = -Subtract @@ First[PlotRange /. First@AbsoluteOptions[txtbase, PlotRange]];
c[t_] := {Cos[2 π t], Sin[6 π t]};
totalarclength = NIntegrate[Sqrt[c'[τ].c'[τ]], {τ, 0, 1}];
invarclength = First@NDSolve[{D[$t[s], s] == 1/Sqrt[c'[$t[s]].c'[$t[s]]], $t[0] == 0},
$t, {s, 0, totalarclength}];
NN[t_] := {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}.c'[t]/Sqrt[c'[t].c'[t]];
maptext[s_, Δn_] := With[{t = $t[Mod[s, totalarclength]] /. invarclength}, 
  c[t] + Δn NN[t]];
Manipulate[
  Show[
    ParametricPlot[c[t], {t, 0, 1}],
    Graphics[
      Dynamic@{txt /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> maptext[-fs x/xRange + s0, -fs y/xRange + ΔN]}],
    PlotRange -> 1.5
  ],
  {{ΔN, 0.1}, -1, 1},
  {{s0, 6.45}, 0, totalarclength},
  {{fs, 2, "font scale"}, 0.1, 5}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: can I ask why use `$t` for your function within `NDSolve`?

Comment: At first, to distinguish t as a function of arc length from the parameter t.  In the end, it didn't matter.

Comment: [**A tribute**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/765198) - thanks @MichaelE2 !

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thanks! I'm honored.  One update in my thinking: The trouble that the use of `Abs` in `Normalize` sometimes causes in symbolic manipulation does not really apply here.  One could use the definition `NN[t_] := Normalize@Cross[c'[t]]` instead, since it is evaluated only numerically; or even `NN = Compile[t, #] &@ Block[{Abs = Sqrt[#^2] &}, Normalize@Cross[c'[t]]]`, which will be faster but would have to be reevaluated if `c` changed.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov I posted a more efficient version in reply to your Community post.

Comment: ... and a very excellent version, thanks @MichaelE2 - indeed very efficient.

Comment: The code in @VitalyKaurov's 'A tribute' seems to have lost its Greek letters - \[Pi] in the parametric definition and later the \[CapitalDelta]s. This is viewed in Chrome; in Safari only the \[Pi]s are missing.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Has there been a change to `ImportString[x,"PDF"]. In 13.01, this produces an `Image[NumericArray[___]]` object rather than `Graphic` and code fails. Have I misunderstood something? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 21):

This is just a quick sketching out of an answer (rescales galore!)

```
 textOnCurve[text_, f_, n_, p_: 0.01] := 
    Text[Rotate[text, ArcTan @@ (f[Rescale[n + p, {0, 1}, {p, 1 - p}]] - 
                                 f[Rescale[n - p, {0, 1}, {p, 1 - p}]])], f[n]]

 textCurve[string_, f_, stylef_: (# &), range_: {0, 1}] := 
  With[{chars = Characters@string}, 
  MapIndexed[textOnCurve[stylef@#1, f, Rescale[#2[[1]],{1, Length@chars}, range]] &, chars]]
```

Which can then be used like:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
 Dynamic@(
  f = BezierFunction[pts];
  Show[Graphics[{Point[pts], Line[pts],
     textCurve["Some text here", f, Style[#, 20] &, {0.2, 0.6}]
     }, Axes -> True]
   , ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]])
, LocatorAutoCreate -> True]
```

[image: Curvy Text]

**Update**

This can be improved by adding proper positioning by fixing the lower midpoint in the rotation and position. Also using [Szabolcs very nice equidistant spacings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454/generating-evenly-spaced-points-on-a-curve). However as I have stated in comments kerning is going to be trouble unless it's really taken seriusly into consideration.

```
 textOnCurve[text_,f_,n_,p_: 0.01]:=
 With[{angle=ArcTan@@Subtract@@(f/@Rescale[{n+p,n-p},{0,1},{p,1-p}])},
  Rotate[Text[text,f[n],{0,-1}],angle,f[n]]
 ]

equidistantTextCurve[string_,f_,stylef_: (#&),range_: {0,1}]:=
 Module[{chars,distance},
  chars=Characters@string;
  distance=functionEquidistant[f,Length@chars,range];
  MapIndexed[textOnCurve[stylef@#1,f,distance[[#2[[1]]]]]&,chars]
]

LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
Dynamic@(f = BezierFunction[pts];
 Show[Graphics[{Point[pts], Line[pts],
  equidistantTextCurve["Mathematica.StackExchange.Com", f, 
   Style[#, 18] &, {0.15, 0.8}]
  }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 2], 
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]]), LocatorAutoCreate -> True]
```

[image: Better curve text with equidistant characters]

I'll leave it as an exercise to calculate proper kerning and getting an even better result.

Comment: Great start, but spacing doesn't seem right, both in your image and here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HoOK4.png

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Kerning, the bane of all. Though in seriousness, it might not even be enough to find equidistant spacings unless you are dealing with monospaced fonts, and even if the normal kerning of the font could be accurately captured, it might not look good when curvature is taken into account.

Comment: @jVincent This is why I need also outlined solution where the text is presented as `FilledCurve`s.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov If you know what to do with the kerning, using text shouldn't be a problem. However you might need to convert to filled curves and do some cleaver integration between characters to figure out the kerning. Independent of which you use to draw the symbols, I don't think you'll be able to select the text without extensive workarounds. Since they are individually positioned pieces of text.

Comment: @jVincent I do not know what to do with the kerning. *Mathematica* currently cannot work with it. But the standard technique `ImportString[ExportString["some text","PDF"],"PDF"]` allows to convert glyphs to `FilledCurve`s preserving kernings.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Interesting, you might be able to use that to find good character baseline midpoints and from that the positions after normal kernings. Then at the very least you could get the same positions along the path (using the equidistant function I just added). You might also get better control over positioning and controlling using the Filled form rather then Text.

Comment: @jVincent What you say is possible. One could convert entire string into `FilledCurve`s, then convert every character into `FilledCurve` and finally find a position(s) of that character in the outlined string. Then calculate the kernings from these data.

Comment: This is nice stuff.But I do not see definition of `functionEquidistant` . Also code in your update is not runable on its own. Could please make it self-sufficient?

Answer (score 6):

#### Description

This project was prompted by [this question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56409845#56409845) on Mathematics chat, to which I posted [this reply](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56410599#56410599). I saw that the resultant diagram, if colored properly, looked somewhat like the Yellow Brick Road from [The Wizard of Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)), and so I set out to write code to draw text along a path to get the first example below.

This code operates similarly to Michael E2's, but it does not solve a differential equation, so I hope it might be a bit faster. I guess that this depends on the function defining the curve being followed. If the curve being followed is defined by an `InterpolatingFunction`, then this approach *should* be faster.

This code is also organized into functions that might be easier to use.

`GetMetrics[curve, arg1, arg2, n]`
This function processes the segment of **curve** between **arg1** and **arg2**. It breaks that segment up into **n** pieces and returns the cumulative distances to these segments along with **curve**, **arg1**, and **arg2** for later use by **CurveText** and **LoopText**.
If **arg1** is greater than **arg2**, then **CurveText** and **LoopText** will render on the other side of **curve** going in the opposite direction.

`FindArg[metrics, dist, loop]`
This function is usually ony called by **CurveText** and **LoopText**. It takes the metrics returned by **GetMetrics** and finds the point that corresponds to **dist** along **curve**. If **loop** is True, then **dist** is reduced modulo the length of **curve**.

`GetPDF[text]`
This function returns information about the layout and outlines of **text**. It does this by converting **text** to a PDF and reading it back in. This information will later be passed to **CurveText** and **LoopText**.

`CurveText[metrics, pdf, scale, toff, noff]`
This function uses the **metrics** from **GetMetrics** and the **pdf** from **GetPDF** to return a Graphics object that will render **text** mapped along **curve**.
`scale` determines the rendered size of **text**; a **scale** of 1 will fill the entire length of **curve**.
`toff` is the tangential offset of **text** along **curve**; 1 offsets by the length of **curve**.
`noff` is the normal offset of **text** from **curve**; 1 offsets by the height of **text**.
If **toff** is negative or **scale** plus **toff** is greater than 1, rendering will be extrapolated as far as **curve** will allow.

`LoopText[metrics, pdf, scale, toff, noff]`
This function operates almost identically to **CurveText** except that out of bound rendering is wrapped modulo the length of **curve**. **LoopText** assumes that **curve[arg1]** and **curve[arg2]** are equal and that **curve'[arg1]** and **curve'[arg2]** are in exactly the same direction.

Here is the code that implements these functions:

```
GetMetrics[curve_, arg1_, arg2_, n_] := 
 Module[{dist = N[0], dlist, last = curve[arg1], next, k}, 
  dlist = First@First@Rest@Reap[
   Sow[dist]; 
   For[k = 1, k <= n, ++k,
    next = curve[arg1 + (arg2 - arg1) k/n];
    Sow[dist += Norm[next - last]]; last = next]];
  {curve, arg1, arg2, dlist}]

FindArg[metrics_, dist_, loop_] := 
 Module[{curve, arg1, arg2, dlist, find, lo, hi, n, dlo, dhi, mid, dst, arg},
  {curve, arg1, arg2, dlist} = metrics; 
  find = If[loop, Mod[dist, Last@dlist], dist];
  n = Length[dlist] - 1;
  lo = 1; hi = n + 1;
  dlo = dlist[[lo]]; dhi = dlist[[hi]]; 
  While[hi - lo > 1,
   mid = Floor[(hi + lo)/2]; dst = dlist[[mid]]; 
   If[find >= dst,
    lo = mid; dlo = dst,
    hi = mid; dhi = dst]]; 
  If[dhi > dlo, 
   arg1 + (arg2 - arg1) (lo - 1 + (find - dlo)/(dhi - dlo))/n, 
   If[n > 0, arg1 + (arg2 - arg1) (lo - 1)/n, arg1]]]

GetPDF[text_] := ImportString[ExportString[text, "PDF"], "PDF"]

CurveText[metrics_, pdf_, scale_, toff_, noff_, loop_: False] := 
 Module[{curve, length, grfx, range, width, height, slw, nh, tl, unit, newpt},
  curve = First@metrics;
  length = Last@Last@metrics; 
  grfx = First@First@pdf; 
  range = PlotRange /. First@AbsoluteOptions[pdf, PlotRange];
  {width, height} = range.{-1, 1};
  slw = scale length/width; 
  nh = noff height;
  tl = toff length; 
  unit = If[Greater @@ metrics[[2 ;; 3]], 
    Normalize[#].{{0, -1}, {1, 0}} &, 
    Normalize[#].{{0, 1}, {-1, 0}} &]; 
  newpt = ({1, slw (#2 + nh)}.({curve[#], unit[curve'[#]]} &
    @FindArg[metrics, slw #1 + tl, loop])) &;
  (grfx /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> newpt[x, y])]

LoopText[metrics_, pdf_, scale_, toff_, noff_] := 
 CurveText[metrics, pdf, scale, toff, noff, True]
```

**A Change for Version 12.2**

Lou notes that as of Version 12.2, [the default for Importing PDF is bitmap](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#1811902644). To get outlines, we need to use

```
GetPDF[text_] := 
 ImportString[ExportString[text, "PDF"], "PageGraphics", 
  "TextOutlines" -> True]
```

This does not seem to work on earlier versions, so I have not included this change in the code above.

---

#### Examples

**Follow the Yellow Brick Road**

On Mathematics chat, it was noted that the lines parametrized by
$$
r\cos(\theta-a)=a\tag1
$$
for $a\in[0,4\pi]$ form a spiral and it was asked what that spiral was. After replying that the envelope was parametrized by
$$
(a\cos(a)-\sin(a),a\sin(a)+\cos(a))\tag2
$$
I noted that the result, if colored properly, was reminiscent of the Yellow Brick Road from The Wizard of Oz. I set out to add text along the path.

```
envelope = {# Cos[#] - Sin[#], # Sin[#] + Cos[#]} &;
metrics = GetMetrics[envelope, 0, 4 Pi, 100];
pdf1 = GetPDF[Style["Follow the Yellow Brick Road ", Lighter[Orange, 1/4],
 FontSize -> 36, FontFamily -> "Times"]];
pdf2 = GetPDF[Style["There's No Place Like Home", Lighter[Orange, 1/4],
 FontSize -> 36, FontFamily -> "Times"]];
ParametricPlot[envelope[t], {t, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Lighter[Orange, 1/4], Thickness[1/200]]}, 
 Prolog -> {Darker[Yellow, 1/6], Thickness[1/600], 
  Line[{{# Cos[#], # Sin[#]} + 100 {Sin[#], -Cos[#]},
   {# Cos[#], # Sin[#]} - 100 {Sin[#], -Cos[#]}}&
   /@ Range[Pi/180, 4 Pi, Pi/90]]}, 
 Epilog -> {CurveText[metrics, pdf1, 1/2, 1/4, -1/6], 
   CurveText[metrics, pdf2, 1/4, 3/4, -1/6], 
   CurveText[metrics, pdf2, 1/4, 3/4, 5/6], 
   CurveText[metrics, pdf2, 1/4, 3/4, 11/6]},
 ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

**Lissajous Live**

This is the curve and text from [Michael E2's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16228), but I have put text on both sides of the curve.

```
lissajous[x_] := {Cos[2 Pi x], Sin[6 Pi x]}
fmetrics = GetMetrics[lissajous, 0, 1, 100];
rmetrics = GetMetrics[lissajous, 1, 0, 100];
pdf = GetPDF["some moveable text"];
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[lissajous[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
  Epilog -> {Dynamic[LoopText[fmetrics, pdf, s, t, n]], 
    Dynamic[LoopText[rmetrics, pdf, s, 1 - s - t, n]]}, 
  ImageSize -> 400],
 {{s, 1/10}, 0, 1}, {{t, 5/8}, 0, 1}, {{n, -1/10}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: This does not work with version 12.2. It seems the PDF export/import function does not return the text information but just a bitmap of the text.

Comment: yes its needed. 12.2 has PDF standard 1.7 so it has changed. Without the PageGraphics I get 
First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[].

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117411/discussion-on-answer-by-robjohn-movable-text-on-a-curve).

Answer (score 3):

Very old thread, so apologies if 'old hat'. [Michael E2's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16194/movable-text-on-a-curve) original code can be adapted to work in 3D graphics by removing the third dimension from the derivative that defines the Text3D direction and using Graphics3D and ParametricPlot3D with whatever arbitrary 3D parametric curve is of interest.

```
txt1 = "Now we can follow an arbitrary path in three dimensions." // Characters;
txt2 = "Anything can go here." // Characters;
loopnumber := 1;
textslantangle := { 3 \[Pi]/2, 0};
f[t_] := {6 Cos[2 \[Pi] t], 8 Sin[8 \[Pi] t], 6 Cos[10 \[Pi] t]};
totalarclength = NIntegrate[Sqrt[f'[\[Tau]].f'[\[Tau]]], {\[Tau], 0, loopnumber}];
invarclength = First@NDSolve[{D[$t[s], s] == 1/Sqrt[f'[$t[s]].f'[$t[s]]], $t[0] == 0}, $t, {s,0,totalarclength}];
ds = 1.0;
fs = Scaled[0.05];

(* Use [[1;;2]] to remove the third dimension from the f'[$t] derivative in the Text3D angle *)

Manipulate[Show[ParametricPlot3D[f[t], {t, 0, loopnumber}],
  Graphics3D[{
    Table[Text[Style[txt1[[n]], "Text", FontSize -> fs],f[$t[Mod[s0 + n ds, totalarclength]] /. invarclength], {0,-1.1},textslantangle f'[$t[Mod[s0 + n ds, totalarclength]] /.invarclength][[1 ;; 2]]],{n, Length[txt1]}],
    Table[Text[Style[txt2[[n]], "Text", FontSize -> fs],f[$t[Mod[s0 + n ds, totalarclength]] /. invarclength], {0,1.1},textslantangle f'[$t[Mod[s0 + n ds, totalarclength]] /.invarclength][[1 ;; 2]]], {n, Length[txt2]}]}],
PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.009], Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> {800, 600}], {{s0, totalarclength/15}, 0, totalarclength}, AutoAction -> True]
```

[image: An arbitrary curve and starting-point.]

Comment: Should be `6 Cos[10 π t]` or `6 Cos[10 π*t]`.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks.