# Animating a circle to move along an curve

Tags: graphics, animation

Basically, I want to move a graphic (such as a circle) along a given path (such as sin(x)). I was thinking that the trick might be making the x and y coordinates of the circle vary based on the equation, but I have not been able to make anything except a circle that just sits there.

Comment: Have a good look at the help for [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) and `Circle` and `Graphics`. Also, the [demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/) site is bound to yield some relevant code...

Comment: In addition, it is always a good idea to post the code you´ve tried already so we get an idea how to best help you out.

Comment: Thank you! I'll make sure to post my erroneous code in the future. And I'll definitely be spending time on that demonstrations site, it's awesome.

Comment: You could (and should) still add your code to the question - this will help future visitors to make more quickly sense of this thread and see how `PlotRange` can help them in similar situations.

Comment: The techniques discussed in this [previous question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16194/movable-text-on-a-curve) would seem to be relevant to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the `PlotRange`:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];

Manipulate[Graphics[{Circle[{x, f[x]}, 0.5]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-2, 2}}], {x, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: Thank you, the missing PlotRange was exactly my issue. Thanks so much for the speedy response!

Comment: I'm new too, and that was exactly the problem I had!