# Text flow into user-defined outline

Tags: regions, text, generative-art

I'd like to flow text into a region defined by a curve, such as:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {5, 2}, {6, -1}, {7, 3}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}};
Graphics[BezierCurve[pts]]
```

[image]

The text must *flow* so that every character appears, as shown [here](https://www.istudiopublisher.com/help-pages/pgs/text-flow-tool.html).

Here is an example from [this page](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-SVG12-20041027/flow.html).

[image]

(It is unacceptable to use the contour to produce a *mask* and "hide" some characters outside the contour.)

I could put in new line characters by hand, but this is unacceptable as the regions are quite complex, and every time I adjust the font size I'd have to go back and alter every new line character by hand.

It is also important that the final figure be in .eps (or .pdf), so some pixel-based methods simply will not work.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what flow means?

Comment: Simply fill the region with the letters in sequence order:  https://www.istudiopublisher.com/help-pages/pgs/text-flow-tool.html

Comment: a Y problem (that may well be as difficult as the X problem): Can we  keep the original ordering of the words/characters in input string and suppress randomization of positions in `WordCloud`? If we knew how to solve the Y problem we could use something like `WordCloud[MapIndexed[DynamicWrapper] @StringSplit[strng," "|"\n"|","],Graphics[{White,FilledCurve[{BezierCurve[pts]}]}, Background->Black],FontSize->{Scaled[.01],Scaled[.01]},ImageSize->Large,PreprocessingRules->None, WordSelectionFunction->(True&),ColorFunction->(Black&),WordSpacings->{15,15}]`

Comment: @kglr:  Thanks.  Can you modify your code to work on just a paragraph or two of given text?

Comment: David, I used the first argument in the 4th example in [WordCloud  >> Scope >> Data](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordCloud.html) as `strng`.

Comment: @kglr:  Oh gee... it works!  Post this as a solution and I'll accept it.  Again, you solve the subtle, hard problems and prove again an unsurpassed knowledge of *Mathematica*.

Comment: David, on v12.0.0 on Wolfram Cloud front-end the ordering of characters is not preserved and the vertical positions of words are jittered (they are not on a straight line). Do you not get the same issue on desktop version? (thank you again for the kind words btw)

Comment: @kglr:  Ah... I had just realized that word order is not preserved, so no... this doesn't quite work.  I'm v. 11.3.0 on a Mac.

Comment: the approaches in the q/a's  [How can I wrap text around a circle?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5719/125) and  [Movable text on a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16194/125) also look promising as a first step.