# How to draw a protractor in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, visualization

I would like to draw a protractor with *Mathematica*. I hope this is a fun question. Here is some start codes I tried:

```
r1 = 0.95; r2 = 0.98; r3 = 0.9; R = 1;
Show[{ParametricPlot[{{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {2 x/Pi - 1, 0}}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Black], 
  Table[ParametricPlot[{{Cos[i Degree] x, x Sin[i Degree]}}, {x, r2, 
     R}, PlotRange -> {-R, R}], {i, 0, 180}], 
  Table[ParametricPlot[{{Cos[i Degree] x, x Sin[i Degree]}}, {x, r1, 
     R}, PlotRange -> {-R, R}], {i, 0, 180, 5}], 
  Table[ParametricPlot[{{Cos[i Degree] x, x Sin[i Degree]}}, {x, r3, 
     R}, PlotRange -> {-R, R}], {i, 0, 180, 10}]}, Axes -> False]
```

[image: start figure]

I draw this protractor just for fun. I hope someone may be interested in this question. As advice from @shrx, the skeleton of the protractor is drawn. However, the labels are not easy for me to add, the alignment and direction are not easy task to do. Any suggestion on this part?

Here are some protractor designs from wiki:

[image: wiki]

[image: wiki 1]

### Thanks for @george2079's answer

The correct way to draw this kind object is directly draw each part, not as in the question using parametric equations to draw. I slightly modified @george2079's answer based on @wxffles's suggestion.

```
Graphics[{{Thickness[.003], Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], 
   Circle[{0, 0}, .03], 
   Line[{{1, 0}, {1, -.1}, {-1, -.1}, {-1, 0}}]},
  {Thickness[.001], Line[{{-0.015, 0}, {0.015, 0}}], 
   Line[{{0, -0.015}, {0, 0.015}}]},
  Rotate[{Thickness[.003], Line[{{.03, 0}, {.6, 0}}]}, #, {0, 
      0}] & /@ {0, Pi/2, Pi},
  GeometricTransformation[
     Piecewise[{{{Red, Line[{{.8, 0}, {1, 0}}], Black, 
         Line[{{.2, 0}, {.5, 0}}], 
         Rotate[{Red, 
           Text[Style[#, FontSize -> Scaled[0.028], 
             FontFamily -> "Times"], {.75, 0}, {0, 0}]}, -Pi/2], 
         Rotate[{Black, 
           Text[Style[180 - #, FontSize -> Scaled[0.026], 
             FontFamily -> "Times"], {.65, 0}, {0, 0}]}, -Pi/2]}, 
        Mod[#, 10] == 0}, {{Blue, Line[{{.85, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
        Mod[#, 5] == 0}, {Line[{{.9, 0}, {1, 0}}], True}}], 
     RotationTransform[# Degree]] & /@ (Range[0, 180])}]
```

[image: from answer]

**Thank you all for your answers and comments!**

Comment: Please edit your post in the form of a question. Right now it is unclear what you're asking. You have clearly managed to draw a protractor, it's just missing some finishing details.

Comment: @shrx texts alignment and direction are quite tough question for me.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Related to your text rotation issue http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5719/193

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], Circle[{0, 0}, .03], 
     Line[{{1, 0}, {1, -.1}, {-1, -.1}, {-1, 0}}],
     Rotate[ Line[{{.03, 0}, {.6, 0}}] , #, {0, 0}] & /@ {0, Pi/2, Pi},
  GeometricTransformation[
     Piecewise[{
       {{Red, Line[{{.8, 0}, {1, 0}}], Black, 
         Line[{{.2, 0}, {.5, 0}}], 
          Rotate[{Red, Text[#, {.75, 0}, {0, 0}]}, -Pi/2], 
          Rotate[{Black, 
             Text[Style[180 - #, Larger], {.65, 0}, {0, 0}]}, -Pi/2]}, 
            Mod[#, 10] == 0},
       {{Blue, Line[{{.85, 0}, {1, 0}}]}, 
            Mod[#, 5] == 0},
       {Line[{{.9, 0}, {1, 0}}], True}}], 
           RotationTransform[# Degree]] & /@ (Range[0, 180])}]
```

[image]

the mathematicians version...

```
formpi[v_] := Module[ { frac = v/Pi,num,den },
   num = If[Numerator[frac] == 1, Unevaluated[Sequence[]], 
                                  Numerator[frac]];
   den = If[Denominator[frac] == 1, Unevaluated[Sequence[]],
               {"/", Denominator[frac]}];
   Switch[
     frac, 1, Pi , 0, 0,
         x_Integer, Row[{frac, Pi}],
         x_Rational, Row[{num, Pi}~Join~den], __, Row[ {v/Pi, Pi}  ] ]]
  Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0, Pi}], Circle[{0, 0}, .03], 
  Line[{{1, 0}, {1, -.1}, {-1, -.1}, {-1, 0}}], 
  Rotate[Line[{{.03, 0}, {.6, 0}}], #, {0, 0}] & /@ {0, Pi/2, Pi}, 
  GeometricTransformation[Piecewise[{
    {{Red, Line[{{.8, 0}, {1, 0}}], Black, 
      Line[{{.2, 0}, {.5, 0}}], 
       Rotate[{Red, Text[Style[formpi[#]], {.75, 0}, {0, 0}]}, -Pi/2],
       Rotate[{Black, 
       Text[Style[formpi[Pi - #]], {.65, 0}, {0, 0}]}, -Pi/2]}, 
         Mod[#, Pi/4 ] == 0},
     {{Blue, Line[{{.85, 0}, {1, 0}}], Black, 
             Line[{{.2, 0}, {.5, 0}}], 
           Rotate[{Red, Text[Style[formpi[#]], {.75, 0}, {0, 0}]}, -Pi/2],
        Rotate[{Black, 
            Text[Style[formpi[Pi - #]], {.65, 0}, {0, 0}]}, -Pi/2]}, 
          Mod[#, Pi/12] == 0}, {Line[{{.9, 0}, {1, 0}}], True}}], 
       RotationTransform[# ]] & /@ (Range[0, Pi  , Pi/180])}]
```

[image]

Comment: May I suggest using a relative font size?  Instead of something like `Style[#, Larger]`, I like to use `Style[#, FontSize->Scaled[0.02]`.  It makes it easier when resizing and exporting graphics.

Comment: This one is great!

Comment: Very nice - I feel like a cro-magnon cave artist when I see results like this, +1

Comment: @wxffles good point, I didn't realize you could do specify a `Scaled` `FontSize`.

Answer (score 10):

This is not a protractor, but it is a related application that that serves as an example of rotated text which is the only thing missing in the protractor shown in the question.

I did it a while a go and keep it near the kitchen oven:

```
c[f_]:=5/9 (-32+f)

f[c_]:=1/5 (160+9 c)

cToAngle[c_]:=(c+40)/300*(2\[Pi]-5Degree)

fToAngle[f_]:=(f+40)/540*(2\[Pi]-5Degree)

Module[{k1=0.86,k2=1.128},
  Graphics[
    {Style[Text["\[Degree]C\[LeftRightArrow]\[Degree]F",{0,0}],FontSize->50],
     Style[Text["C[F_] := 5/9(F-32)",{0,.3}],FontFamily->"Courier"],
     Style[Text["F[C_] := (160+9 C)/5",{0,-.3}],FontFamily->"Courier"],
     Table[{Line[{k1{Sin[cToAngle@c],Cos[cToAngle@c]},{Sin[cToAngle@c],Cos[cToAngle@c]}}],
            Text[ToString[c]<>"\[Degree]C",k1{Sin[cToAngle@c],Cos[cToAngle@c]},{1,0},{Sin[cToAngle@c],Cos[cToAngle@c]}]},
           {c,-40,260,10}],
     Table[{Line[{{Sin[fToAngle@f],Cos[fToAngle@f]},k2*{Sin[fToAngle@f],Cos[fToAngle@f]}}],
            Text[ToString[f]<>"\[Degree]F",(k2+0.125){Sin[fToAngle@f],Cos[fToAngle@f]},{1,0},{Sin[fToAngle@f],Cos[fToAngle@f]}]},
           {f,-40,500,20}],
     AbsoluteThickness[0.1],
     Table[{Line[{{Sin[fToAngle@f],Cos[fToAngle@f]},(1.1)*{Sin[fToAngle@f],Cos[fToAngle@f]}}]},
           {f,-40,500,2}],
     White,Point[{0,0}]},BaseStyle->{FontSize->Larger}
  ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very interesting.

Comment: This doesn't make a good protractor because this circle weirdly has 540 degrees, and not 360 ;-P

+1