# How to draw a clock-diagram?

Tags: graphics

I found a clock-diagram in a paper, so I would like to draw it in Mathematica. The main trouble for me is the corresponding line segments on the circle.

I would let the `data1` lie the outside on the circle, and `data2` lie the inside of the circle.

[image]

```
data1 = Range[0, 1, 0.2]
data2 = Range[0, 1, 0.15]

Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Line[{{0, 0.8}, {0, 1.2}}], 
 Text[Style["0", 20], {0, 0.65}], 
 Arrow[Reverse@Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi, Pi/2, 0.1}]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86054/2079

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the line position and arc distances, I take this to be the correct configuration, though the inital image has weird proportions.

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Line[{{0, 0.8}, {0, 1.2}}], 
  Arrow[Reverse@Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi, Pi/2, 0.1}]], 
  Table[Line[{{2 Sin[θ], 
      2 Cos[θ]}, {(2 + 
         0.2 (-1)^(θ 12/Pi)) Sin[θ], (2 + 
         0.2 (-1)^(θ 12/Pi)) Cos[θ]}}], {θ, 0, 
    2 π, π/12}], Text[Style[0, Large], {0, 0.6}]}]
```

[image]

Note that the line segments alternate in and out, simply change all the `12` to whatever number to increase or decrease the amounts of lines.

Answer (score 13):

In case you're not familiar with the [`Gauges`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Gauges.html) in Mathematica:

```
Show[{
  AngularGauge[.7, {0, 1}, 
    GaugeMarkers -> Placed[Automatic, "ScaleRange"], 
    ScaleOrigin -> {π/2, -3π/2}, 
    GaugeStyle -> {Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.5]], None}, 
    GaugeFrameStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.5]], 
    GaugeFrameSize -> .02],
  Graphics[
   {Directive[Red],
    Table[Line[{1.1 {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, 1.15 {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}}], {θ, 0, 2π, π/6}] }]
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
Graphics[{
  Circle[{0, 0}, 2],
  Line[{{0, 0.8}, {0, 1.2}}],
  Arrow[Reverse@Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi, Pi/2, 0.1}]],
  Rotate[Line[{{0, 2}, {0, 2.2}}], 2 Pi # , {0, 0}] &  /@ 
   Range[0, 1, 1/12],
  Rotate[Line[{{0, 1.8}, {0, 2}}], 2 Pi # , {0, 0}] &  /@ 
   Range[1/24, 23/4, 1/12]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: My initial answer may have let my error slip into your code too. The inner lines are displaced with $\frac{\pi}{12}$

Comment: @Feyre Corrected, Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

```
data1 = Range[0, 1, 0.2]
data2 = Range[0, 1, 0.15]

 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2], Line[{{0, 0.8}, {0, 1.2}}], 
  Arrow[Reverse@Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -π, π/2, 0.1}]], 
  Red, Line[{{2 Cos[-(2 π # - π/2)], 2 Sin[-(2 π # - π/2)]}, 
        {2.2 Cos[-(2 π # - π/2)], 2.2 Sin[-(2 π # - π/2)]}}] & /@ data1,
  Blue, Line[{{1.8 Cos[-(2 π # - π/2)], 1.8 Sin[-(2 π # - π/2)]}, 
        {2 Cos[-(2 π # - π/2)], 2 Sin[-(2 π # - π/2)]}}] & /@ data2,
   Text[Style[0, Large], {0, 0.6}]}]
```

[image]

**Other data**

```
data1 = {0.0838886, 0.188029, 0.27299, 0.351457, 0.425728, 0.5, 
 0.574272, 0.648543, 0.722815, 0.801282, 0.886242, 0.990383}

data2 = {0, 0.0742716, 0.202914, 0.277185, 0.351457, 0.425728, 0.5, 
  0.574272, 0.648543, 0.722815, 0.797086, 0.871358}
```

[image]