# Text Mapping Very Slow

Tags: graphics

I want to change the transformation in the following code (from Dr. belisarius [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5719/how-can-i-wrap-text-around-a-circle)) so that the word "circle" goes outward from the rightmost position of the circle and rotates counterclockwise as does my handwritten "circle" in the graph:

[image]

The code of Dr. belisarius:

```
Module[{l = 
Cases[First[First[ImportString[ExportString[Style["CIRCLE", Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier", 
     FontSize -> 12], "PDF"], "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]], 
FilledCurve[a__] :> {EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, FilledCurve[a]}, Infinity]}, 
Animate[Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5], {l /. {x_Real, y_Real} :> 
   y^(1/10) { Sin[t + 1/100 Norm[x, y]], 
              Cos[t + 1/100 Norm[x, y]]}}}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
AnimationRunning -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

In other words, instead of the mapping

```
{x,y}:> 
y^(1/10) { Sin[t + 1/100 Norm[x, y]], 
          Cos[t + 1/100 Norm[x, y]]}}}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}
```

what is the mapping that will make the text read outward from the center of the circle?

Using `FindGeometricTransform` I can get the transformation but not in a general form. If I put `FindGeometricTransform` in the code then it is excruciatingly slow. Any ideas? Slow code:

```
Module[{l = 
   Cases[First[
     First[ImportString[
       ExportString[
        Style["CIRCLE", Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier", 
         FontSize -> 12], "PDF"], "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]], 
    FilledCurve[a__] :> {EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, FilledCurve[a]}, 
    Infinity]},
 Animate[Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 30], {l /. {x_Real, y_Real} :>
       FindGeometricTransform[{
           RotationMatrix[t].{20, 0}, RotationMatrix[t].{30, 0}, 
           RotationMatrix[t + b].{30, 0}, 
           RotationMatrix[t + b].{20, 0}},
          {{0, 3}, {32, 3}, {32, 8}, {0, 8}}][[2]]@{x, y}}}, 
   Axes -> True], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {{b, Pi/24}, Pi/64, Pi/2}, 
  AnimationRunning -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try something like `{x,y} :> (0.7 + 0.025 x) {Cos[t + 0.05 y], Sin[t + 0.05 y]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pursuant to Simon Woods's answer, this works nicely:

```
Module[{l = 
   Cases[First[
     First[
      ImportString[
       ExportString[
        Style["CIRCLE", 
         Bold, FontFamily -> "Courier", 
         FontSize -> 12], "PDF"], "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]], 
    FilledCurve[a__] :> {EdgeForm[Black], Yellow, FilledCurve[a]}, 
    Infinity]},
 Animate[Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 2], {l /. {x_Real, y_Real} :>
       (0.7 + 0.025 x) {Cos[t + 0.05 b y], Sin[t + 0.05 b y]}}}, 
   Axes -> True],
 {t, 0, 2 Pi},
 {{b, .5}, .01, 1}, 
  AnimationRunning -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True]]
```